# Switching Cards Around in Monopoly Deal 2

Tags: monopoly-deal

Firstly, I know that there is a question on switching cards after charging rent on them. However, the case I did is a bit more extreme.

I had 2 green, 2 red, 2 light blue, 1 yellow, and a multi-colour wild property card.

Firstly, I moved the wild card from its original position, with the yellow, to the green and make it a full set. (This counts as 0/3 of my moves.)

Then, I charged everyone 7M each. (1/3)

After receiving the money, I moved the wild card to the red set, and charged everyone 6M each. (2/3)

After receiving the money, I moved the wild card to the light blue set, and charged everyone 3M each. (3/3)

Then, I moved the wild card back with the yellow card.

Is **any** part of my moves out of the Monopoly Deal rules? Although I don't think so, people are saying that I might have cheated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the rules [here](http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=general#top) it says (emphasis mine)

> Each player can play up to 3 cards per turn. A play is considered any
>   time **a card is laid on the table** (such as money into your bank,
>   property cards on the table, action cards played into the middle,
>   etc). You do not need to play all 3 cards per turn if you do not want
>   to.

The same website in there strategy section [here](http://monopolydealstrategy.com/index.php?page=money) says

> It’s important to remember that you can re-arrange your monopoly cards
>   on the table during your turn without sacrificing one of your three
>   moves. This simple fact can help you maximize your income when
>   charging other players.

You are allowed up to 3 'plays' a turn  this is defined as placing a card on the table.  moving a card from set to another is not one of you 3 'plays'